# Secure login across two web apps

Tags: encryption, web-application, authentication

I have an requirement to implement cross-domain login for two web apps (APP1 and APP2) so that a user can access APP2 once they have logged into APP1.
APP2 needs to know an ID of the user who is logged into APP1. 
I have come up with a solution but I'm not sure it's the best way to do it. Could you please take a look at this solution and point out potential vulnerabilities or give me some hints how to get it done in a better way?
Here's the solution:

1. APP1 has a link to the APP2 somewhere on the website. The link contains a login token which is generated by APP1's server, i.e. https://app2.somedomain.com/index.html?login-token=U2FsdGVkX1+S5BDg4DV0nnoq3iIEjAj6Wk48F20GjNWGZDoad8VgAW9nG4ltBV0iQNuFz428yqh6pQ6JcKMIO9c+hy9+BDGfDfqz6tuCqp4=
2. A login token is a plain text encrypted using a symmetric key algorithm such as AES and an encryption password which is known only by APP1 and APP2. 
   It contains the following information: 
   userId, ip address, timestamp, secret-key, 
   ie. 
   00001,87.143.203.12,1399725213,secret-key
3. APP2 receives the request, decrypts the login token using the encryption password and checks the following:

   - HTTP referer - it should match to the APP1 server URL
   - IP address
   - secret-key - both apps share the same secret-key (is not the same as the encryption password) to verify that the request comes from APP1
   - whether the login token has been used or not.
4. APP2 guarantees that a login token can be used only once so it won't be possible to steal a login token and use it to access APP2 from another computer.

Answer (score 3):

I would use an open source implementation of [OAuth](http://oauth.net/).  Even better,  you could use a 3rd party OAuth provider so that you don't have to worry about leaking your customer's credentials in the event of a compromise.

Comment: Thanks Rook. I've been thinking about OAuth but it might be a problem to get guys behind APP1 to implement OAuth. I don't want to go into details here, I was just wondering if there's any simpler solution which would be secure enough.

Comment: @janusz  i would strongly advise against building your own crypto system,  this is the most complex and risky thing you could do.  Leave that to the cryptographers.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the recommendation to use OAuth.

For analysis of your proposal, I recommend you read the following blog post:

- [If You're Typing The Letters A-E-S Into Your Code, You're Doing It Wrong](http://web.archive.org/web/20110620022453/http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2009/7/22/if-youre-typing-the-letters-a-e-s-into-your-code-youre-doing.html), Thomas Ptacek, Matasano, July 2009.